# Keep track of items in array with delimiter python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I take in a user supplied input string array that can look like the following:

```
x=[100.0,150.0,200.0:300.0:10.0,300.0,350.0:400.0:10.0,500.0,600.0:700.0:10.0,800.0,900.0]
```

As these are user supplied lists, the ordering of the interval slices [e.g., 200.0:300.0:10.0] can vary, as can the individual entries without slices.

Then I split on the ':," delimiters, so I can covert to from float to string for use in numpy.r_. I then get the following list:

```
x_arr=[100.0,150.0,200.0,300.0,10.0,300.0,350.0,400.0,10.0,500.0,600.0,700.0,10.0,800.0,900.0]
```

I would like to keep track of the original index where the ":" delimiter existed as well as where the ":" delimiter was absent so that I can reconstruct the original array as a series of floats in the following way:

```
np.r_[100.0, 150.0, slice(200.0,300.0,10.0), 300, slice(350.0,400.0,10.0), 500.0, slice(600,700,10),800,900]
```

The issue is how to keep track of the change in indices from the original array to the new array in a consistent manner. I would appreciate any ideas as to how to best implement this with random user supplied input.

Here's one way I thought about approaching it:

I split the original array on ',' to find the elements that are missing the ":" delimiter:

```
x_no_colon=re.split((','),x)
xh=[]
for ind in x_no_colon:
    inds_wo_colon=re.findall(":",ind)
    xh.append(inds_wo_colon)
```

which using the above example would return the following:

```
xh=[[],[],[":",":"],[],[":",":"],[],[":",":"],[],[]]
```

Then I can identify the indices without colons in the following manner:

```
x_wo_colons = [item for item in range(len(xh)) if xh[item] == []]
```

which would return:

```
x_wo_colons=[0,1,3,6,8,9]
```

Then I find the indices with the ':' delimiter using an array split on ':' :

```
colon_arr=re.split('(:)',x)
prelim_x_with_colon=[item for item in range(len(colon_arr)) if colon_arr[item] == ':']

x_w_colon=[]
for i in prelim_x_with_colon:
    if i == 1 and colon_arr[1] != ':':
        x_w_colon.append(i)
    elif i == 1 and colon_arr[1] == ':':
        x_w_colon.append(i-1)
    else:
        x_w_colon_append(i-1)
```

With a list of indices where colons exist and don't exist the only thing to do would be to remove the indices w/o colons from the list w/colons. The issue I've found here is that it's hard to get the indices correct each time for varying lists. This might be because my approach is convoluted and I'm using two different arrays for the different lists.

The issue is how to keep track of the change in indices from the original array to the new array in a consistent manner. I would appreciate any ideas as to how to best implement this with random user supplied input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Moses Koledoye here's the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to convert this input string/list in to a list/array of numbers, taking into account that some items look like slices?

Here's my experiment with your string (minus the `[]`).  I'll leave a lot of the trial and error in.  It might be instructive.

```
In [957]: txt='100.0,150.0,200.0:300.0:10.0,300.0,350.0:400.0:10.0,500.0,600.0:700.0:10.0,800.0,900.0'
```

I assume `,` is the primary delimiter,  `:` secondary

```
In [958]: txt.split(',')
Out[958]: 
['100.0',
 '150.0',
 '200.0:300.0:10.0',
 '300.0',
 '350.0:400.0:10.0',
 '500.0',
 '600.0:700.0:10.0',
 '800.0',
 '900.0']
```

define a function to process one of these items:

```
In [960]: def foo(astr):
     ...:     items=astr.split(':')
     ...:     if len(items)==1:
     ...:         return float(items[0])
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return slice(*[float(i) for i in items])
     ...:     
In [961]: [foo(s) for s in txt.split(',')]
Out[961]: 
[100.0,
 150.0,
 slice(200.0, 300.0, 10.0),
 300.0,
 slice(350.0, 400.0, 10.0),
 500.0,
 slice(600.0, 700.0, 10.0),
 800.0,
 900.0]

In [962]: np.r_[_]
Out[962]: 
array([100.0, 150.0, slice(200.0, 300.0, 10.0), 300.0,
       slice(350.0, 400.0, 10.0), 500.0, slice(600.0, 700.0, 10.0), 800.0,
       900.0], dtype=object)
```

It creates slices like I expected, but `np.r_` doesn't accept literal slices; it requires the `:` syntax.  Actually it's the Python interpreter that does that, converting the `[a:b:c]` into `slice(a,b,c)` object.  Seems we addressed that issue recently.  Rather than fight that, let's jump directly to `arange` (since `np.r_` translates the `slices` to `arange` or `linspace` anyways).

```
In [963]: def foo(astr):
     ...:     items=astr.split(':')
     ...:     if len(items)==1:
     ...:         return float(items[0])
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return np.arange(*[float(i) for i in items])

In [964]: [foo(s) for s in txt.split(',')]
Out[964]: 
[100.0,
 150.0,
 array([ 200.,  210.,  220.,  230.,  240.,  250.,  260.,  270.,  280.,  290.]),
 300.0,
 array([ 350.,  360.,  370.,  380.,  390.]),
 500.0,
 array([ 600.,  610.,  620.,  630.,  640.,  650.,  660.,  670.,  680.,  690.]),
 800.0,
 900.0]

In [965]: np.concatenate(_)
...
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Oops, `concatenate` doesn't like the single numbers;

```
In [966]: def foo(astr):
     ...:     items=astr.split(':')
     ...:     if len(items)==1:
     ...:         return [float(items[0])]
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return np.arange(*[float(i) for i in items])

In [967]: [foo(s) for s in txt.split(',')]
Out[967]: 
[[100.0],
 [150.0],
 array([ 200.,  210.,  220.,  230.,  240.,  250.,  260.,  270.,  280.,  290.]),
 [300.0],
 array([ 350.,  360.,  370.,  380.,  390.]),
 [500.0],
 array([ 600.,  610.,  620.,  630.,  640.,  650.,  660.,  670.,  680.,  690.]),
 [800.0],
 [900.0]]

In [968]: np.concatenate(_)
Out[968]: 
array([ 100.,  150.,  200.,  210.,  220.,  230.,  240.,  250.,  260.,
        270.,  280.,  290.,  300.,  350.,  360.,  370.,  380.,  390.,
        500.,  600.,  610.,  620.,  630.,  640.,  650.,  660.,  670.,
        680.,  690.,  800.,  900.])
```

Looks good.

=======================

In a recent answer I did find a way of passing literal `slice` objects to `r_`, in a tuple.

```
In [969]: def foo1(astr):
     ...:     items=astr.split(':')
     ...:     if len(items)==1:
     ...:         return float(items[0])
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return slice(*[float(i) for i in items])
...
In [971]: tuple([foo1(s) for s in txt.split(',')])
Out[971]: 
(100.0,
 150.0,
 slice(200.0, 300.0, 10.0),
 300.0,
 slice(350.0, 400.0, 10.0),
 500.0,
 slice(600.0, 700.0, 10.0),
 800.0,
 900.0)

In [972]: np.r_[tuple([foo1(s) for s in txt.split(',')])]
Out[972]: 
array([ 100.,  150.,  200.,  210.,  220.,  230.,  240.,  250.,  260.,
        270.,  280.,  290.,  300.,  350.,  360.,  370.,  380.,  390.,
        500.,  600.,  610.,  620.,  630.,  640.,  650.,  660.,  670.,
        680.,  690.,  800.,  900.])
```

Comment: To have np.r_ accept the literal slices I did np.concatenate([np.r_[i] for i in x]) (if x is the array). Thanks! The function is a pretty clever way of doing it!

Comment: Do you know if using np.arange is faster than just using the slice function? Or are they pretty equivalent in your experience?

Comment: `r_` uses `arange` to turn the `slice` into the numbers.   Look at the code in `lib/index_tricks.py`

Answer (score 1):

You said the input array is a string, so (using your example):

```
x = '[100.0,150.0,200.0:300.0:10.0,300.0,350.0:400.0:10.0,500.0,600.0:700.0:10.0,800.0,900.0]'
```

Then we split `x` by `,` and then the elements by `:`:

```
x = x[1:-1].split(',')
x = ([float(y) for y in elt.split(':')] for elt in x)
```

I made `x` into a generator, but it is now essentially

```
[[100.0], [150.0], [200.0, 300.0, 10.0], [300.0], [350.0, 400.0, 10.0], [500.0], [600.0, 700.0, 10.0], [800.0], [900.0]]
```

At this point I don't know how to create the array you want with `numpy.r_`, but I think the same goal can be achieved by

```
x = (y if len(y) == 1 else np.arange(*y) for y in x)
result = np.hstack(x)
```

Here `np.arange` is numpy's `range` that takes `float` arguments, and `np.hstack`, according to its docstring, "Stack arrays in sequence horizontally (column wise)."

Comment: Wow, this works great! I tested it on a bunch of random input and it seems to do the trick every time perfectly.